# Running the turtlebot on fuerte/12.04

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Does a tutorial for setting up my workstation for interacting with the turtlebot under fuerte exist yet? I am working on a recently rebased Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04 computer. To change over the turtlebot I followed this:

```
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/Robots(2f)TurtleBot(2f)fuerte(2f)Robot(20)Upgrade.html
```

I understand fuerte is a new release, but I was unable to find any good notes on how to patch my workstation.

Thanks!
-Parker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34873/running-the-turtlebot-on-fuerte/12.04/) by [0pc0](https://answers.ros.org/users/1936/0pc0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this by doing

- sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
- sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot
- sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-apps
- sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-viz

It should get your workstation in good working order with dashboard and what not.. Wish they would have not mirrored my untested wiki mod for fuerte yet.

---

Originally posted by [blackstag](https://answers.ros.org/users/2841/blackstag/) with karma: 26 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1